# What is wrong with my constructor Function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, return

I am having trouble with my constructor function and need help, here is what I have so far...

```js
function EgyptianGoddesses(name, oversees, strength, weakness) {
  this.name = name;
  this.oversees = oversees;
  this.strength = strength;
  this.weakness = weakness;

  return function() {
    name,
    oversees,
    strength,
    weakness
  }
  
}

var maatCharacteristics = ['Maat', 'Truth and Justice', 'Balancing and Just', 'Exacting in her standards']

var maat = new EgyptianGoddesses(this.maatCharacteristics)
console.log(maat)
```

I am just getting an empty constructor, and I think it is something wrong with the return. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't return anything from the constructor, omit even the `return` statement.

Comment: `new EgyptianGoddesses(this.maatCharacteristics)`  You don't want the `this` here, it works here only because `this` context is going to be global, and the var is currently global.  Seen as `maatCharacteristics` is in scope, just do `new EgyptianGoddesses(maatCharacteristics)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
var maat = new EgyptianGoddesses(this.maatCharacteristics)
```

Should pass the arguments from the variable, not a property, and should spread them out.

```
var maat = new EgyptianGoddesses(...maatCharacteristics)
```

Now the individual members of `maatCharacteristics` will be passed to the individual parameters of the constructor.

Not sure why you're returning a function that does nothing. You'll need to explain your intent for that to be properly fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can not figure out when and when not to use the spread operator to save my life, and yes I didn't need to return it, not too familiar with constructor functions yet.

Comment: You're welcome. The spread is pretty simple. If you have a collection, and you want to pass the members of the collection as individual members, use the spread syntax. It also works with array literals, for example: `var newArr = ["foo", "bar", ...maatCharacteristics]` That creates a new array that includes the members of your original array.